# How Use a Property of a Model in Eloquent Querying Relations

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have three Models. University, Professor and Student.
They have some relations.

1. University Model :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\User;

class University extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'user_id'];

    /**
     * Get the user that owns the university.
     */
    public function owner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

2. Professor Model :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\University;
use App\Models\Student;

class Professor extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'surname', 'university_id'];

    /**
     * Get the university where the professor teaches.
     */
    public function university()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(University::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get the student associated with the professor.
     */
    public function student()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Student::class)->withDefault();
    }
}
```

3. Student Model :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\University;
use App\Models\Professor;

class Student extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'surname', 'age', 'university_id', 'professor_id'];

    /**
     * Get the university where the student is studying.
     */
    public function university()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(University::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get the professor of the student.
     */
    public function professor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Professor::class);
    }
}
```

Every professor belongs to a university.
Every student belongs to a university.
Every student has exactly one professor, but a professor may not have a student.

**The Question :
How can I have a list of students who are at the same university with their professor?**

*The following code is incorrect!*

```
$students = Student::select('id', 'name', 'surname', 'age', 'university_id')
->whereRelation('professor', 'university_id', '=', ***'student.university_id'***) 
->with(['university', 'professor'])
->orderBy('id', 'desc')
->paginate(20);
```

Thanks.

Comment: in what case would a student be at a different university than their professor?

Comment: maybe A visiting professor at a university

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the **$universityId**, you should follow the 1st example. Otherwise, you can get all students by grouping **university_id**

1st example:

```php
$students = Student::with(['university', 'professor'])
              ->where('university_id', '=', $universityId)
              ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
              ->paginate(20);
```

2nd example:

```php
$students = Student::with(['university', 'professor'])
              ->groupBy('university_id')
              ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
              ->paginate(20);
```